# CMake: how to build additional files for an existing target?

Tags: cmake

I need to generate extra files for an existing CMake target that is already defined with an `add_executable()`; I don't know how many files there are in advance, and in addition those files are not compiled/part of the executable itself. These files should be build or updated whenever I build that target, but *only* if their dependent files have been updated.

These extra files are generated and/or updated from an existing file with a Python script. So the natural choices are `add_custom_target()` and `add_custom_command()`, but I run into two issues with these:

- `add_custom_target()` works and I can add that as an additional depency of the main target, but the scripts are **always** executed.
- `add_custom_command()` has proper dependency tracking, but I cannot add the **files** as dependencies of the main target, CMake simply won't allow it.

So what does not work:

```
function(register_translation_files)

    ## determine TARGET and INPUT_FILES ...
 
    foreach (LANG IN LISTS TRANSLATION_LANGUAGES)
        message ("Add translation '${LANG}' for target ${TARGET}")
        set (XLF_FILE "${TARGET}_${LANG}.xlf")
        add_custom_command (
            OUTPUT ${XLF_FILE}
            COMMAND scripts/cet2xlf.py --language ${LANG} ${XLF_FILE} ${INPUT_FILES}
            DEPENDS ${INPUT_FILES}
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        )
    
        add_dependencies (${TARGET} ${XLF_FILE})   <<--- fails with '('the dependency target of TARGET does not exist')
    endforeach()
endfunction()

(....)

add_executable (MainTarget foo.cpp bla.cpp)
register_translation_files (TARGET MainTarget INPUT file1 file2)
```

add_custom_target works but is always executed (as CMake considers it always outdated):

```
function(register_translation_files)

    ## determine TARGET and INPUT_FILES ...
 
    foreach (LANG IN LISTS TRANSLATION_LANGUAGES)
        message ("Add translation '${LANG}' for target ${TARGET}")
        set (XLF_FILE "${TARGET}_${LANG}.xlf")
        add_custom_target (
            ${XLF_FILE}
            COMMAND scripts/cet2xlf.py --language ${LANG} ${XLF_FILE} ${INPUT_FILES}
            DEPENDS ${INPUT_FILES}
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        )
    
        add_dependencies (${TARGET} ${XLF_FILE})   <<--- builds, but script is executed every time!
    endforeach()
endfunction()

(....)

add_executable (MainTarget foo.cpp bla.cpp)
register_translation_files (TARGET MainTarget INPUT file1 file2)
```

I tried all kinds if variations, including a custom_target with dependencies on custom_command output, but I either end up with 'this dependency does not exist' or a script that is always executed.

Surely, one can add **files** with `add_depencies()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine both `add_custom_target` and `add_custom_command` to accomplish this:

List the files generated by `add_custom_command` in via the `DEPENDS` option of [`add_custom_target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) and then use `add_dependencies`.

I strongly recommend keeping the source directories free of any files generated during build/cmake configuration. Not doing this prevents projects you set up based on the same source directory from working properly.

```
function(register_translation_files)

    ## determine TARGET and INPUT_FILES ...
 
    set(OUTPUT_DIR ${CMKAE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated_translation_files)
    file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${OUTPUT_DIR})

    set(GENERATED_FILES)

    foreach (LANG IN LISTS TRANSLATION_LANGUAGES)
        message ("Add translation '${LANG}' for target ${TARGET}")
        set (XLF_FILE "${OUTPUT_DIR}/${TARGET}_${LANG}.xlf")
        add_custom_command (
            OUTPUT ${XLF_FILE}
            COMMAND "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/scripts/cet2xlf.py" --language ${LANG} ${XLF_FILE} ${INPUT_FILES}
            DEPENDS ${INPUT_FILES}
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${OUTPUT_DIR}
        )
        list(APPEND GENERATED_FILES ${XLF_FILE})
    endforeach()
    add_custom_target("${TARGET}_generate_translations" DEPENDS ${GENERATED_FILES})
    add_dependencies(${TARGET} "${TARGET}_generate_translations")
endfunction()
```

---

> Surely, one can add **files** with `add_depencies()`?

No, this is not possible. This is hinted at in [the documentation of `add_dependencies`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html) alongside hinting at the solution presented above:

> add_dependencies( [<**target**-dependency>]...)
>
> [...]
>
> See the `DEPENDS` option of `add_custom_target()` and `add_custom_command()` commands for adding file-level dependencies in custom rules.

Comment: "I strongly recommend keeping the source directories free of any files generated during build/cmake configuration." Well, the XLF files are checked in source control as they are part of the translation cycle. These files are not just generated but updated/merged with new strings. I'll update the question to reflect that.